# Given Chararray which is alphabetically sorted back to the original

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

I have this code:

```
Console.WriteLine("TextEingabe!");
string eingabe = "Hallo, das ist mein Text";/* Console.ReadLine(); */

char[] ausgabe = eingabe.ToCharArray();

Console.WriteLine(ausgabe[4]);
Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;

Array.Sort(ausgabe, new CharComparer(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("lt")));  // Right result using string comparer.
Console.WriteLine(new string(ausgabe));

foreach (char word in ausgabe)
{

}
```

I am sorting my `eingabe` alphabetically, and then showing it to the screen with `Console.WriteLine`. Then I use a `foreach` loop to write out the characters.

I expected the array would still display the original text in the `foreach` loop. I also tried to make it work with the index but it looks like the old index gets overwritten by the new, which means "H" is not in the [0] position.

Can someone give me an example and explains it ?

In case it helps, here is the `CharComparer`:

```
readonly CultureInfo culture;

public CharComparer(CultureInfo culture)
{
    this.culture = culture;
}

public int Compare(char x, char y)
{
    return string.Compare(new string(x, 1), 0, new string(y, 1), 0, 1, false, culture);
}
```

Comment: Why you don't post the code instead of the picture?

Comment: Why post a picture that you have to do a screen shot of, then upload, instead of a simple copy and paste of the code?

Comment: i actually didnt know how to Format it right

Comment: Done, hope its better

Comment: `Array.Sort` is going to mutate your `ausgabe` char array.  If you want the original you'd have to get it from the `eingabe` string again.  Note you could just do `foreach(char c in eingabe)` since `string` implements `IEnumerable<char>`.

Comment: Well so there is no other way to get it back from ausgabe, since the index is mutated ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `eingabe` in your foreach loop:

```
foreach (char word in eingabe)
{

}
```

Or if you want to use the `ausgabe` array you can simply call again  `ausgabe = eingabe.ToCharArray();` :

```
ausgabe = eingabe.ToCharArray();

foreach (char word in ausgabe)
{

}
```

Comment: Thank you that is what i am searching for i actually tried to make the first example but i was just being stupid and made in with ausgabe instead of eingabe...